# Azure command "az keyvault secret list" throws "[Errno 22] Invalid argument" - how to debug?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, error-code

I am running the Azure command-line interface (**azure-cli**) against an Azure key vault.

I do this:

```
$ az keyvault secret list --vault-name <name-of-my-vault> --maxresults 10
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

This command once worked, but a week or two ago it stopped working and started throwing this error (`[Errno 22] Invalid argument`). How can I debug this?

I am logged in with `az login`. My account has the following security roles (RBAC) for the key vault in question:

- Owner
- Contributor
- Key Vault Certificates Officer
- Key Vault Secrets Officer

I have version 2.30.0 of **azure-cli** installed. I got the same error in 2.27.0. I also see it on a Jenkins build server, running 2.27.0.

My key vault contains a bit over 200 secrets (a few of them have multiple versions). None of them are expired; in fact none of them have an expiration date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, this works for me in version 2.27.0 and 2.30.0, I don't believe that the syntax has changed at all. I do have one question - did you update az cli to 2.30.0 between the time that it last worked and now? I ask because the 2.30.0 broke authentication for the az devops extension (AAD/MSAL authentication no longer works, only workaround is an Azure DevOps PAT). If you did indeed upgrade, it's conceivable that release broke other things as well.

Comment: also, check the activation and expiration dates on your secrets, per https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16683

Comment: I was using 2.27, and it suddenly broke. I tried to upgrade to fix it, but that made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the answer by @RamaraoAdapa-MT, I think I found the answer. There were no bad *secrets* in my vault, but there appears to have been a bad *certificate*. I deleted this certificate from my vault, and now I can get secrets again.

[image: Where to find certificates in vault]

I have created a GitHub issue for the maintainers of azure-cli: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20241

Comment: I'd recommend going over to Github and filing an issue for that - the command should still return what secrets it can, and it certainly shouldn't return an "invalid option" error!

Comment: Good point. Done: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20241

Answer (score 1):

As @WaitingForGuacamole suggested in the comment section, I have tested in my environment

I created secrets in the Key Vault with expiration dates as follows:

[image]

Now, I logged in to Azure CLI and ran the below command:

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name <name-of-my-vault> --maxresults 10
```

I got the same error:

[image]

Now, I deleted the secret with expiration date: 1/1/3008 and ran the same command again

It ran without any error. It listed the secrets in my key vault

So, the best way to debug the issue is to check the expiration date of all the secrets in the key vault. Make sure to have the expiration date of secrets before 3000-01-01

Comment: Alas, none of my secrets even HAVE an expiration date.

Comment: do they have an activation date?

Comment: Y3K alert. Start hiring the COBOL devs now.